# digitally signing the pdf document embedded on razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to get the data from active directory. this is my code:

```
   UserPrincipal up = UserADIdentity.GetADUserInfo(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString());
public static UserPrincipal GetADUserInfo(string userName)



    {

        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))

        {

            UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

            userPrincipal.SamAccountName = userName;

            userPrincipal.Enabled = true;

            userPrincipal = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal).FindOne() as UserPrincipal;

          }

    }
```

Code works fine on my local computer, but when I deploy the code to IIS on server. This line of code:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString()
```

is always returning NULL. I am not sure how to fix it. My code is running under applicationPoolIdentity.This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Are the server and client computers in the same AD domain?

Comment: No, they are not

Comment: I think they should be in the same Ad Domain.

Comment: They are in same AD domain. I tried to change my answer above, but couldn't.

Comment: I seems misunderstood something, try to login with another account, like administrator? I need to know more detail, you also could create a new sample project for without any sensitive info, I am glad to narrow down this issue.